# Java driver for Datacom: SQL syntax issues

Tags: java, sql, groovy

Any Java/Groovy developers who work with Datacom out there?

Looks like the Java driver for Datacom won't let me do things like:

```
select top n column from table
```

or

```
Order By Rnd
```

without throwing syntax error exceptions.

The gist of what I'm trying to do is a randomized select top n or randomized select min from table. The randomization is critical.

This query fails on the "group by" line:

```
Select min(column) as columnAlias From table
Inner Join anotherTable On table.column = anotherTable.column
Group By Rnd(numericColumn)
Order By Rnd(numericColumn)
```

This query fails on the "select top" line - it appears to want a cursor declared (Error is DECLARE SQL_JCUR_CA_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 5). This strikes me as really odd.

```
Select top n column as columnAlias From table
```

These queries run OK in MS Access. I've looked through the Datacom SQL docs but nothing is jumping out as the potential problem.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND` is usually a **terrible** performer, because it effectively has to sort your entire result set, _then_ get the top number of rows.  Besides which, I'm not sure how 'good' (evenly distributed) the results are.  You may be better off dumping the rows into a new table (with an autogen id) and having client-side code generate ids to fetch (with a crypto-level psuedo-random generator).  Also, your `GROUP BY RND(numericColumn)` probably wouldn't be doing what you want, even if it was performant.  What is your actual situation, so we can advise you better?

Comment: More simply stated, I need to get x random rows from a Datacom table with some restrictions specified in a WHERE clause. I can do this with select top n or even select min() in SQL Server 2005, and even in MS Access going up against Datacom tables. No method I've tried yet has worked with the jdbc Datacom driver. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: So... run a statement dumping the rows from the `WHERE` clause into a table with an auto-gen id, then select them out based on the new ids (technically, the only other column the new table needs is the id for the initial table, but you may as just well make it the entire column list).  Nicely short-cuts your problem, and will probably be a lot better performer, too.

Comment: I wound up using the offset parameter, an optional argument to Groovy's eachRow method, as the value to randomize. This avoids the issue of making the DB implementation do the randomizing.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question (and accept it), although you should usually wait for other parties to have the chance.  Also, just using the offset ('start at row') is unlikely to be good enough, if you're using it to grab more than one row at a time.  Mostly, this manifests itself in rows being chosen in predictable sets (ie if row 5 is chosen, 6 will be as well).  Also, unless you specifically account for edge cases, the end rows have a smaller chance of being included (your set has to loop to the start of the table again).

Comment: Agreed that the offset method is not the optimal answer to the randomization issue, but in my case (and given my limited Groovy programming skills) it was "good enough." I generally do like to follow up with what I wound up doing, whether or not it was something different than one of the answers given, in the case of someone like me who has the same question. Clockwork-Muse, thanks for your help and I might try to figure out a Groovy way of using your method.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer, especially when the question hasn't received an answer in this long.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the reason for the message "Error is DECLARE SQL_JCUR_CA_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 5", "select top n" is not valid CA Datacom SQL syntax. To select a limited number of rows you would need to specify "select [columns list] from table where...**fetch first n rows only**". It is the "fetch first n rows only" clause that limits the number of rows returned from the result set.

I am currently beta testing the latest version of CA Datacom/Server 15.0 so if there are further syntax questions please let me know.